# facebook api returns null email

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, email, facebook-graph-api, hybridauth

I am trying to use hybridauth with codeigniter for Facebook login. I have successfully set up a Facebook app with all the basic permissions. I am primarily interested to get the email address of the user so that I can create an account in the application. I have checked the integration and it seems to work. However, in the response I receive, I get everything as either null or string(0), even the email. Below is the response.

```
["description"]=> string(0) "" 
["firstName"]=> string(0) "" 
["lastName"]=> string(0) "" 
["gender"]=> string(0) "" 
["language"]=> NULL 
["age"]=> NULL 
["birthDay"]=> NULL 
["birthMonth"]=> NULL 
["birthYear"]=> NULL 
["email"]=> string(0) "" 
["emailVerified"]=> string(0) "" 
["phone"]=> NULL      
["address"]=> NULL ["country"]=> NULL 
["region"]=> string(0) "" 
["city"]=> NULL 
["zip"]=> NULL
```

This data is from my own fb id and I have set everything to public. I do not receive any error. My application asks for permission for email which I have set up in the scope parameter. Still I do not get the email.

Please help

Comment: Please add the code you're using to get the profile data from Facebook.

Comment: API v2.4 changed what fields endpoints return by default; in a lot of cases, one now has to specifically ask for the fields that should be returned.

Comment: Thanks for the responses... it turned out that the FB app was in 2.4 and the HAuth code was for an earlier version. I modified the FB provider file to support 2.4.